# Tableview cell blink and position change while reloading cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in my app in tableview cell i am using more button for load more content when click on more button. so on click of more button i am reloading that particular cell. but when i reload that cell that cell go upside and some blink effect happen. i want it smooth like instagram that when we tap on more button its just increase the height of cell without any position change.

Here is my code
:

```
@objc func btnMorePressed(sender : UIButton) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell : FeedTableViewCell = (tblQuote.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? FeedTableViewCell)!
    cell.btnMore.isHidden = true
    cell.lblCaption.numberOfLines = 0

    quoteArray[indexPath.row].numberOfLines = 3
    tblQuote.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .none)
     tblQuote.beginUpdates()
    tblQuote.endUpdates()
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order around to:

```
tblQuote.beginUpdates()
tblQuote.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
tblQuote.endUpdates()
```